# Mono.Data.SQLite reference missing in MonoDevelop "Edit References"

Tags: monodevelop

On Windows, I installed MonoDevlop and tried compiling the SQLite example which requires the Mono.Data.SQLiteClient reference. I opened up "Edit References" within MonoDevelop and I have absolutely no Mono references available with the exception of Mono.Cairo and Mono.Posix.

I thought perhaps I'd made a mistake by no installing the Mono framework first, so I installed Mono, then did a repair installation on MonoDevelop but the references are still not there?

Can somebody help me please?

Cheers
Sparky

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, I believe Mono.Data.SqliteClient has been deprecated in favour of Mono.Data.Sqlite.

By default, MonoDevelop on Windows targets the .NET runtime for building/running/etc. The libraries available in the "Edit References" dialog are those installed into the target runtime, i.e. .NET.

If you have Mono installed, you also have the choice of targeting Mono. You can change the default target runtime using the *Preferences->.NET Runtimes* options panel, or change it for only the current solution using the *Project->Active Runtime* Menu.

Regardless which runtime you build with, you should be able to run/debug with another runtime using the *Run->Run With...* menu.

You could also install Mono.Data.SQLite into the [.NET AssemblyFolders](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306149).

Comment: Perfect!! Thanks mhutch. It works. Very happy now - I can start some serious cross-platform development for PC and Mac.

Comment: Please note that you can't use Mono.Data.Sqlite 4.0.0.0 on .net 4.0 as there is a blocking bug caused by security permissions.