# Missing Sqlite Assembly in Mono Project

Tags: c#, sqlite, mono

I'm having a go at porting an open source .Net project to OSX (Mountain Lion) using Mono. My first step was to try building the project and seeing what errors I get.

The code makes use of System.Data.Sqlite which appears under 'References'. I have Sqlite installed on OSX but obviously am missing the Mono equivalent. How can I include this in the project? Eventually I guess I will have to do conditional compilation but for now, would just like to get things working.

Here's the error:

```
Assembly 'System.Data.SQLite, Version=1.0.65.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=db937bc2d44ff139, processorArchitecture=x86' not found. Make sure that the assembly exists in disk. If the reference is required to build the project you may get compilation errors.
```

Answer (score 0):

You need the managed assembly containing the ADO.NET provider for SQLite.

[System.Data.SQLite](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/index.wiki)

Mono also provides Mono.Data.Sqlite assembly, which is API compatible although you would need to change your 'using' statements to use the correct namespace. More on that here:

[Mono.Data.SQLite reference missing in MonoDevelop "Edit References"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3649025/mono-data-sqlite-reference-missing-in-monodevelop-edit-references)

Since you are building on the Mac, I'd be tempted to just reference Mono.Data.Sqlite and adjust your 'using' statement with conditional compilation.